# How to mock wait method of waiting pip module

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

i am using waiting module for python, in a class I have this method:

```
from waiting import wait
class Manager:
    @staticmethod
    def wait_answer(timeout, title):
        RunningContext.inputResponse = None
        wait(lambda: InputClientLayer.is_answer_ready(), timeout_seconds=timeout, waiting_for=title)
```

In my test I did:

```
@mock.patch('waiting.wait')
def test_wait(self, wait):
    myClass = Manager()
    myClass. wait_answer(60, 'Test')
```

But the function did not mocked!

Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `@mock.patch('yourmodule.wait')`

Comment: it did not work!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, if file name to test is Manager.py inside a package for example "helpers" you can mock with:

```
@mock.patch('helpers.Manager.wait')
def test_wait(self, wait):
    myClass = Manager()
    myClass. wait_answer(60, 'Test')
```